# .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False ERROR excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

i get an error at the ".Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False" line

this macro used to work fine on my machine, when i transfered to the virtual machine it didn's work and the error i get was this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSaJ2.png)

my code :

note,, all the paths have been changed to the new ones, so no problem with that

```
Sub Csv()

Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Path
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

 Workbooks.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="account_Transactions_Other", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""C:\Users\Alfalakbot4\Desktop\New folder\account_Transactions_Other.txt""),[Delimiter=""#(tab)"", Columns=7, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.Csv])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Change Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{""Column1"", type text}, {""Column2"", type text}, {""Column3"", type text}, {""Column4"", type text}, " & _
        "{""Column5"", type text}, {""Column6"", type text}, {""Column7"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Change Type"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=account_Transactions_Other;Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [account_Transactions_Other]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "account_Transactions_Other"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("account_Transactions_Other").Unlist
    Rows("1:4").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Style = "Normal"
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
    Range("A1").Select

Workbooks(2).Activate
  
End Sub
```

Comment: note, the macro worked fine with excel 365, but didn't when i migrated to 2016

Comment: I am afraid that it is not a matter of different Excel  installation. As the error states, please better check if the path to the file is correct. Maybe ".csv" instead of ".txt", some more/less spaces in the query etc.

Answer (score 2):

`ListObject.Refresh` doesn't take any parameters, and is only available for lists linked to SharePoint.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject.refresh